# How to check checkbox if the datagridview column value="True"

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview

I want to set my datagridview checkbox checked or unchecked according to the datagridview column value.

If datagridview column[3] value="true" checkbox checked

If datagridview  column[3] value="false" checkbox unchecked

```
//my code as follows:
foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView3.Rows)
{
     DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)r.Cells[0];
     string inceleme = r.Cells[3].Value.ToString();

     if (inceleme=="Evet")
     {
         chk.Value = chk.TrueValue;           
     }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20452844/how-to-check-if-datagridview-checkbox-is-checked

Comment: it is not possible duplicate please read my question carefully

Comment: So if I got it right, you want all the checkboxes in a column checked if the text in the column header has either the text  "true" or "false"? I can't really recall myself what the value of a column is.

Comment: try with `Checked` property, instead of `if (inceleme = "Evet")` block, just make one line like this: `chk.Checked = inceleme=="Evet";`

Comment: Not all checkboxes only one checkbox with row. if the text in the same row column @steven

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `for`-loop instead of `foreach`? If I am not mistaken foreach creates readonly copies on which you work.